# Variable not Updating Accurately in Game Loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm creating a game in Java. I have a game loop that only runs 60 times per second, like below:

```
public void run() {

    double variable = 0;

    init();

    double delta, start, now, lastTime;
    double fps = 60.0;
    double timePerUpdate = 1000000000 / fps;
    delta = 0;
    lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    start = lastTime;

    while (running) {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerUpdate;
        lastTime = now;

        if (delta >= 1) {
            variable += delta / fps;
            delta = 0;
            System.out.println((now - start) / variable / 1000000000);
        }
    }

    stop();
}
```

This is highly simplified, but it shows basically what I'm doing. I have some variable which I want to increase by 1 every second, but increase it by about 1/60 every frame so that it in total increases by 1 every second.

At the end of updating, I'm printing the total time elapsed, divided by the variable, divided by  1000000000 (conversion to seconds).

This should print `1` because the variable is being increased by 1 every second, but instead, it is printing `0.8`, `0.9`, `0.95`, `0.99`, `0.999`, etc. approaching 1. Why isn't it exactly one?

Comment: It seems likely that there's an integer division or other rounding issue messing something up somewhere, but it's unclear from the code you've given. What types are `start`, `delta`, `lastTime`, and `now`? Do you realize that integer-division-and-truncation is occurring on the line where you set `timePerUpdate`?

Comment: Change the increment logic to delta = delta + 1/60.0 and see what happens.

Comment: It's more about math (limit calculation) than programming. As ```variable``` incrases, the result goes to 1, I think.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] that reproduces the issue. Aside from the integer division which VeeArr pointed out, as it is, we're just guessing.

Comment: I updated my code, but none of the above things worked.

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce this code adequately, hence your question is liable to downvotes. Where is the "running" variable? Where did you define "init()" and "stop()". I sent you a suggested edit to make your code cleaner.

Comment: *"I updated my code"* Did you read the document linked by @Radiodef before doing that? An MCVE is not the same as an uncompilable code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It is not printing exactly one because the CPU is not exactly checking the if condition when the difference is 1.

Meaning that you continuously increase the delta until it is greater than 1. Once it reaches 1 you take the last delta computed and calculate the *variable* and then ask him to print the difference. The explanation for why it seems it is reaching one it might be because: as the difference in time grows exponentially, also the accuracy of the computation decreases and it tends to go toward 1. So reaching 1  might be the rounded answer of your computed values.

See this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    run();
}
public static void run() {

    double variable = 0;


    double delta, start, now, lastTime;

    double fps = 60.0;
    double conversionRate = 1000000000.0;
    delta = 0;

    lastTime = System.nanoTime();

    start = lastTime;

    int counter = 1;
    while (true) {

        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / conversionRate;
        lastTime = now;

        // It fires every second or so 
        if (delta >= 1) {
            delta = 0;
            System.out.println("Counter is: " + counter++);
        }
    }
}
```

This program counts 1 every second. Every second does not fire *exactly* 1 second. The errors arise from the way you are calculating the expression in the print statement.

Comment: So are you saying that the variable is being updated correctly, but the reason why the printed value is incorrect is because of when the print function is called?

Comment: I have updated with some code so you can understand better. I would like also to mention that when you divide by the fps rate, you are calling the if statement 60 times per second.